# программа правильно работает только с числами, содержащими не более 9 разрядов

Tags: c++, for, while

Только учусь программированию. Решила попробовать написать программу, которая считает, сколько разрядов в числе, и выводит, чему равен каждый из разрядов. Программа работает с числами, в которых до 9 разрядов включительно, но если я ввожу число с 10 и более разрядами, то она выводит некорректный результат. Как это объяснить или как исправить? [image: результат работы с 11 разрядами]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");

    int n{}, k{}, nc{}, r{};

    cout << "деление числа на разряды \n";
    cout << "введите целое число: ";
    cin >> n;

    nc = n;
    while (nc > 0) {
        k ++;
        nc = nc / 10;
    }
    
    cout << "в вашем числе " << k << " разряд";
    
    for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
        r = n % 10;
        cout << i << "-ый разряд равен " << r << "\n";
        n = n / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Максимальное значение, представимое 32-битным типом `int` равно `2'147'483'647`. При попытке ввести через стандартный поток ввода большее число в переменную типа `int`, ей присваивается максимальное для данного типа значение. Именно это значение и выводится в консоль (наоборот). Думаю, самый надёжный способ в вашем случае — считать _строку_, затем подсчитать кол-во цифр в ней, либо вообще считывать посимвольно, наращивая счётчик цифр, до тех пор, пока не наткнётесь на символ, отличный от цифры...

Comment: @wololo поняла, спасибо огромное!

Comment: кстати, если мы вам помогли, не забудьте поставить стрелочку вверх и нажать на галочку. Тем самым, вы отблагодарите!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### То число которое Вы ввели слишком большое для переменной `n`.

Следовательно, происходит переполнение переменной.

Диапазон `int'a` — от `-2 147 483 648` до `2 147 483 647`. Чтобы эго расширить, нужно добавить спецификатор `long long`.

Тогда диапазон будет от `−9 223 372 036 854 775 808` до `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`.

Кстати, есть альтернативный вариант решения Вашей задачи:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");

    long long int n{};
    string txt_num;

    cout << "деление числа на разряды \n";
    cout << "введите целое число: ";
    cin >> n;

    txt_num = to_string(n);

    cout << "в вашем числе " << txt_num.length() << " разряд" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < txt_num.length(); i++) 
    {          
        cout << i << "-ый разряд равен " << txt_num[i] << '\n';       
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Так хитрее и быстрее. Просто нужно сконвертировать в `string`.

Comment: ой, спасибо большое! помогли разобраться :)

Comment: служу `stackoverflow`!

Answer (score 2):

Десятизначное число не влезает в `int`. До 18 знаков- `long long`

И скобки фигурные ни к чему лишние